# Необходима помощь с ffmpeg

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg

У меня есть скрипт CMD, который позволяет записывать трансляцию с Youtube в файл.
Необходимо это видео делить на куски (по времени, или по размеру) "на лету" (во время трансляции).

Задав вопрос на github библиотеки streamlink (эту библиотеку использую для записи), мне ответили что это можно реализовать с помощью ffmpeg.

Кто нибудь может помочь с этой задачей, так как с ffmpeg я не работал)

Текущий скрипт:

```
:loop

set day=%DATE:~0,2%
set month=%DATE:~3,2%
set year=%DATE:~6,4%

set hour=%TIME:~0,2%
set minute=%TIME:~3,2%
set second=%TIME:~6,2%

set YYYYMMDD=%day%_%month%_%year%_%hour%_%minute%_%second%


streamlink --hls-live-edge 99999 --hls-segment-threads 10 --ringbuffer-size 1024M -o %YYYYMMDD%.ts https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbt5BCs0aUDgNwRaUnKtXwA best
goto loop
```

Похожие попытки, которые я пытался реализовать:

1. C помощью определенных команд streamlink указывал время начало запись и длительность записи. Не получилось, так как запись не заканчивалась сразу, а докачивалась до ближайшего конца блока, тем самым получалось наложение двук кусков видео почти на 1 минуту, что делает невозможность монтажа (так как будет дополнительные затраты на синхронизацию участков.
2. Идея была скачивать определенное количество блоков (например 001, 002, 003, 004, 005), а потом записывать начиная с 006 и так каждые 5 блоков. Не получилось, так как у streamlink я не нашел команды для получения блоков, а вопрос на github мой просто закрыли